# Create Sharepoint HyperLinks Help

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to saves multiple hyperlinks to a list. Can anyone guide me where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Morski,

Your description is somewhat vague, but you have a list type called Links that is made for this exact purpose.

.b

Comment: Hi! I am Beginner in this thats why i dont now what to ask.